# TDateEdit, how to set year before to 1900 in calendar picker dialog?

Tags: android, delphi, view, calendar, firemonkey

My app in android (developed in Delphi XE8 Firemonkey) needs to search for data prior to the year 1900, I use a TDateEditor, when user clicks to select dates the android calendar picker dialog doesn't allow dates with years less than 1900, I'd read about styles.xml and testing without success, with the code below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="DateEditStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.CalendarView">
            <item name="android:endYear">2100</item>
            <item name="android:startYear">1800</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And styles.xml deployed in the remote path "res\values\". Nothing works, how can I solve this?, What do I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `startYear` and `endYear` are not attributes of `CalendarView`, they are attributes of `DatePicker`, which uses `CaneldarView` fields internally when its mode is `spinner`. In any case, `startYear` and `endYear` were deprecated in API Level 16, use `minDate` and `maxDate` instead (which `CalendarView` also has attributes for).

Comment: Thanks Remy, but still does not works, min year 1900 yet.                                              `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="DateEditStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.CalendarView">
         <item name="android:minDate">01/01/1800</item>
         <item name="android:maxDate">12/31/2100</item>
 </style>
</resources>`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem is in the type that contains the data (or the way TDateEdit processes it). As
[Embarcadero says](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TDate):

> TDate represents a special type of TDateTime value that has no decimal part. A TDate value represents the number of days that have elapsed since 12/30/1899.

I guess that is why you can not use the standard component to select such dates. It seems you need to declare your own TDate type and/or develop a component with necessary functionality (able to process negative values for example).

Comment: Thank you, I finally desisted, so I added 6 comboboxes (2 for each day, month and year to start and end) where the user picks the desired value.